# Can't close IIS Worker Process. Can't soft restart Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, iis-8.5

I'm a developer using the IIS to host my web applications, both home and a the office.

At work my project is built using ASP.NET WebAPI on the server side and HTML/AngularJS on the client side.

At home my project is built using node.js on the server side and HTML/AngularJS on the client side.

I don't remember when this problem started, but sometimes my IIS Worker Process just stops working.  Sometime this occurs after I've had my computer running a couple of days, sometime after a couple of minutes.

I can shut it down in the IIS Manager, but when I look at the ist of worker processes it's there with the state "stopping".

When I check in the task manager I have a process "IIS Worker Process" reading from the hard drive at 12-15 MB/s. When I try to shut it down in the task manager, nothing happens. No error message or anything.

When I try to shut it down using Sysinternals pstools I get the message `Unable to kill process w3wp: access denied`.

When I try to delete all files in the folder, I'm not allowed to remove one of them (a JavaScript file) because something is using it. The only thing I can find in the event log (right now is the first time I see this, so it might be a coincidence) is:

```
Windows har upptäckt att din registerfil fortfarande används av andra program eller servrar. Filen tas nu bort ur minnet. Programmen eller tjänsterna som använder registerfilen kanske inte fungerar korrekt efter detta. Ingen användaråtgärd krävs.  

 INFORMATION - 
4 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-599682246-432979038-111007333-4100006191-103776784_Classes:
Process 1236 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-599682246-432979038-111007333-4100006191-103776784_CLASSES
Process 1236 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-599682246-432979038-111007333-4100006191-103776784_CLASSES
Process 1100 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-599682246-432979038-111007333-4100006191-103776784_CLASSES
Process 1236 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-599682246-432979038-111007333-4100006191-103776784_CLASSES
```

The message is in Swedish, but I hope the information part can tell something